# PHP: Why is array not changed while using reference in function call?

Tags: php, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to understand some code and there's something I don't get.
The code uses a reference to an array in the arguments and a reference in the function block. I've created the following sample code:

```
function some_function(&$array)
{
    // assign a value to a new key in the empty array
    $array['somekey'] = 'somevalue';

    // set the array to reference this key
    $array = &$array['somekey'];

    // var_dump() of the array shows 'somevalue'
    var_dump($array);
}

$my_array = [];
some_function($my_array);

// var_dump() now shows the initial value of ['somekey'] => 'somevalue' ???
var_dump($my_array);
```

Below is the output of the 2 var_dumps.

> ```
> string(9) "somevalue"
> array(1) {
>   ["somekey"]=>
>   string(9) "somevalue"
> }
> ```

My question is: Why is the second assignment ignored after leaving the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function some_function(&$array){} takes the address of the first element $array[0] of the **array-argument** as the reference address. Within the function, reassignments merely changed the value at $array[0] as $array was reassigned to **point** to the value at **array['somekey']** and changes to **$array** after reassignment changed the value of **array['somekey']**.

```
<?php 
function some_function(&$array)
{
    // assign a value to a new key in the empty array
    $array['somekey'] = 'somevalue';

    echo gettype($array);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($array);
    echo "<br>";
    // set the array to reference this key
    $array = &$array['somekey'];


    // var_dump() of the array shows 'somevalue'
    var_dump($array);
    echo "<br>";
    echo gettype($array);
    echo "<br>";
    $array='different value';
    echo "<br>";
    echo gettype($array);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($array);
}

    $my_array = [];
    echo "<br><br>";
    var_dump($my_array);
    some_function($my_array);

    echo "<br><br>";
    // var_dump() now shows the initial value of ['somekey'] => 'somevalue' ???
    var_dump($my_array); // ['somekey'] shows 'different value' because the value was changed in the function.
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo gettype($my_array);
    echo "<br><br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because references don't work like C pointers.

> There's no way to bind $my_array in the calling scope to something else using the reference mechanism since $my_array is not available in the function some_function()

Read the PHP manual at [What References Are Not](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php)

Answer (score 0):

The second assignment is not ignored. Let's break the code down line by line.

```
$my_array = [];
some_function($my_array);

function some_function(&$array)
{
```

Now the symbol `$my_array` (in the global scope), and the symbol `$array` (in the local scope of the function) are both references to the same empty array.

```
// assign a value to a new key in the empty array
$array['somekey'] = 'somevalue';
```

This modifies the array, and both symbols still reference it.

```
// set the array to reference this key
$array = &$array['somekey'];
```

This line tells PHP that the symbol `$array` should now reference the string 'somevale'. But the symbol `$my_array` is not affected by it. If you want to change the value that both symbols reference, you simply use a normal assignment:

```
$array = $array['somekey'];
```

and both var_dumps will show the same.